# Log4J dynamically create log file

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have successfully created a log at each process run time. The issue I am having now is any packages that are called that are not children of the current running process does not write its log to my file. For example I create a new log file called running-.log. The process that is running is com.me.foo inside of this class there is a call to a method in com.you and another one in com.zee . I would like to have com.you and com.zee logs write to the running-.log and not to the console log. It isn't as simple as just changing the getLogger() method to be a child of com.me.foo. Some of the logs are written out from third party jars. I am at a loss. If you need to see more code or some additional info, please let me know. There has to be another way to handle this.

Thanks

Code to create the log file dynamically

```
public void createLogInstance(String packaging,String appenderName, String logFileName){
  Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(packaging);

  Appender fileAppender = logger.getAppender(appenderName);

  if(fileAppender != null){
     logger.removeAppender(fileAppender);
  }

  //Create the root appender
  ConsoleAppender console = new ConsoleAppender();

  String pattern = ....;
  console.setLayout(new PatternLayout(pattern));
  console.setThreshold(Level.FATAL);
  console.activateOptions();

  logger.addAppender(console);

  FileAppender fa = new FileAppender();
  fa.setName(appenderName);
  fa.setFile(logFileName);
  fa.setLayout(new PatternLayout(..));
  fa.setThreshold(Level.DEBUG);
  fa.setAppend(true);
  fa.activateOptions();
  logger.setAdditivity(false);

  logger.addAppender(fa);


}
```

com.zee log

```
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Zee.class);
```

com.you log

```
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(You.class);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the rootLogger. Changed this line

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(packaging);
```

to

```
Logger logger = Logger.getRootLogger();
```

If someone has a better way please let me know.